# How to detect overflow in two-dimensional array of C?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a two-dimensional array like this:

```
[1][0][3]
[0][2][0]
[1][0][0]
```

I should to analyze each position if around it there is a '0', and get that position. After that, I must complete this position with another numbers. The problem is, how detect if the position that i'm analizing not exist, that is if is overlflow?. I know that C has no bounds checking , but there must be a way to check that position.

Comment: You know the array size, `3x3` so check that you indexes are always in a legal range...

Comment: Use nested loops but limit your boundary conditions appropriately. Start at index 1 and stop at row - 2 or height - 2. In the case of the 3X3 in your example, only the [2] in the dead center will be a candidate for checking.

Comment: In the scope where the array is declared, you can use `sizeof()` to get the size of the array. But if you pass the array to a function, it just passes a pointer. You need to pass the size information as well, there's no way for the function to get it by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use GNU Scientific Libraгy or implement 2dimm array with get/set functions. Something like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct Arr {
        double* arr;
        int max_x;
        int max_y;
    } typedef Arr;

    Arr* Arr_new(int x, int y){
        Arr* result = (Arr*)malloc(sizeof(Arr));
        if (result){
            result->arr = (double*)malloc(x*y*sizeof(double));
            result->max_x = x;
            result->max_y = y;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void Arr_free(Arr* arr){
        free(arr->arr);
        free(arr);
    }

    // Arr_set(arr, 0, 0, 3.14) is correct.
    void Arr_set(Arr* arr, int i, int j, double val){
        //replace your code if needed:
        assert(arr->max_x > i);
        assert(arr->max_y > j);
        arr->arr[i + j*arr->max_x] = val;
    }

    // Arr_get(arr, 0, 0) is correct.
    double Arr_get(Arr* arr, int i, int j){
        //replace your code if needed:
        assert(arr->max_x > i);
        assert(arr->max_y > j);
        return arr->arr[ i + j*arr->max_x];
    }


    int main(void)
    {
        Arr* a = Arr_new(3,3);
        Arr_set(a, 2, 2, 1.234) ;
        double val = Arr_get(a,2,2);
        printf("val = %f\n",val);

        Arr_free(a);
        return 0;
    }
```